# Using zip code to display custom data in Admin Order Details

Tags: php, woocommerce-offtopic, post-meta

So I am just trying to display which area of the city a postal/zip code is located in for each order.

I have managed to pull all the correct data and thought I add it sorted out until I realized the following code was just displaying information based on MY account's saved postal/zip code.

I need the displayed result to be based on the SHIPPING zip/postal code of the customer ordering.

Below is what I have:

```
// -------------- DISPLAY CUSTOMER'S CITY LOCATION BASED ON POSTAL CODE ----------/

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_shipping_address', 'end_of_city' );
function end_of_city( $order ) {
    GLOBAL $woocommerce;
    $customer_postcode = get_user_meta( get_current_user_id(), 'shipping_postcode', true );

    $northwest = array('N6G','N6H');
    $northcentral = 'N6A';
    $northeast = array('N5Y', 'N5X');
    $south = 'N6E';
    $southwest = array('N6L', 'N6P');
    $southeast = array('N5Z', 'N6M', 'N6N');
    $west = array('N6J','N6K');
    $east = array('N5V','N5W');
    $central = array('N6B','N6C');


    if ( $customer_postcode !== false ) {
        foreach ($northwest as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>Northwest London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (stripos($customer_postcode, $northcentral) !== false) {
            echo '<h3>North Central</h3>';
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($northeast as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>Northeast London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        if (stripos($customer_postcode, $south) !== false) {
            echo '<h3>South London</h3>';
            return true;
        }
        foreach ($southwest as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>Southwest London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        foreach ($southeast as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>Southeast London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        foreach ($west as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>West London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        foreach ($east as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>East London</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
        foreach ($central as $token) {
            if (stripos($customer_postcode, $token) !== false) {
                echo '<h3>Central / Downtown</h3>';
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried calling and using the following as well but doesn't seem to work:

```
$billing = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_postcode', true );
$shipping = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'shipping_postcode', true );

if ( empty($shipping) ) {
    $customer_postcode = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'billing_postcode', true );
}else {
    $customer_postcode = get_post_meta( $order->id, 'shipping_postcode', true );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED with the below change/addition:

```
$shipping = $order->get_shipping_postcode();

if ( empty($shipping) ) {
    $customer_postcode = $order->get_billing_postcode();
}else {
    $customer_postcode = $order->get_shipping_postcode();
}
```